# User Login With PHP PDO and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, pdo, session-cookies, redirect

I have a form in a popup modal that should be used for user login there are two input fields one for ID card number and second for password .. The collected data are sent by ajax to a php page called login.php that should check the user user entered data and create a session for it if he is active user and transfers him to home page and if he is not active user transfers him to student-registration page and if the entered data are wrong a paragraph within the form should give a notification to the user .. now there is nothing happening when I submit the form where did missed up !!
html strcture:

```
<div id="std-login-modal" class="modal">
    <header class="modal-header">
        <h3>تسجيل الدخول كطالب</h3>
        <i class="fa fa-times modal-close"></i>
    </header>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="std-login-frm" method="POST">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="std-card" name="stdID" autocomplete required>
                <label>رقم القيد</label>
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
                <div class="input-desc">
                    <span>هذا الحقل خاص بادخال رقم قيد الطالب المكون من سبعة أرقام</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" id="std-pass" name="stdPass" required>
                <label>كلمة المرور</label>
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
                <div class="input-desc">
                    <span>هذا الحقل خاص بكلمة المرور الخاصة بالطالب</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="تسجيل دخول" name="stdLoginBtn">
                <p id="std-login-error"></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <footer class="modal-footer">
        <p>لا يوجد لديك حساب في الموقع؟ قم بانشاء واحد</p>
        <button id="create-std-account" class="modal-second-btn">انشاء حساب</button>
    </footer>
</div>
```

My jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Student Login Operation
    $("#std-login-frm").submit(function(e){
        e.prvenetDefault();
        // Get Student Entered Data From The Inputs
        var stdID = $("#std-card").val().trim();
        var stdPass = $("#std-pass").val().trim();

        // Call AJAX Method And Specify Its Parameters
        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php?type=student",
            type: "POST",
            data: {ID:stdID,Password:stdPass},
            dataType:"json",
            error: function(data){
                $("#std-login-error").html(data.fail);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

login.php code:

```
<?php
    include'connect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['stdLoginBtn']))
    {
        $type = '';
        if(isset($_GET['type']))
        {
            $type = $_GET['type'];
            if($type == 'student')
            {
                // Get Data Sent By AJAX POST Request
                $ID = $_POST['ID'];
                $pass = $_POST['Password'];

                // Check if the user exist in database
                $stmt = $con->prepare("select ID,password,status,name,phone,
                token from students where ID=?");
                $stmt->execute(array($ID));
                $info=$stmt->fetch();
                if(password_verify($pass,$info["password"]))
                    {
                        if($info["status"] == 1)
                        {
                            $_SESSION['stdID'] = $info["ID"];
                            header('Location:home.php');
                            exit();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $_SESSION['mobile'] = $info["phone"];
                            $_SESSION['token'] = $info["token"];
                            $_SESSION['name'] = $info["name"];
                            header('Location:student-registration.php');
                            exit();
                        }
                    }
                else
                {
                    $fail = "خطأ في البيانات يرجى إعادة المحاولة";
                    $data = array('error' => $fail);
                    echo json_encode($data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

I also will provide the connection code to mysql:

```
<?php
$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vcm';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$option=array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    );

try{
    $con= new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass,$option);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Failed to connect' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: @tadman:  The questioner is using the generally robust PHP password suite including `password_verify()`. So he's doing OK with password security.  @RaizadaDev: good job adopting that password suite.

Comment: @O.Jones Yes, I've encoded my password as I always do .. Can you see what the error in my code?

Comment: Since you are submitting via an ajax request, the location header has no visible effect - either use a regular form submit, or return the desired location as a json property and perform the redirect in your ajax handlers success callback

Comment: @O.Jones I didn't see that at first, so it's nice to see proper password hashing. The problem with home-rolled login systems remains, these *cannot be trusted* in a production environment, they're way too complex a piece of software to implement ad-hoc.

Comment: @Jasonbamber how can I return the desired location as a json property and perform the redirect in my ajax handlers success callback with setting session? can you please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke [`session_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in your php program before you output anything to a page that uses or sets any session variables.  That allows them to be saved in the session manager, and feeds a cookie to your user's browser identifying the session.  In subsequent web requests the user's browser passes along the session cookie.

Additionally, if your ajax request goes to a different domain than the one served by your page, you should include this in your ajax options.

```
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    }
```

Finally, the browser doesn't look at any `Location:` header returned in a response to an AJAX request (only in a page response). You need to process that header yourself in your Javascript code.

Something like this may do the trick for you:

```
success: function(data, text, request){
     document.location.href = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
}
```

Putting it all together, your ajax request might look like this (**not debugged**).

```
    // Call AJAX Method And Specify Its Parameters
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php?type=student",
        type: "POST",
        data: {ID:stdID,Password:stdPass},
        dataType:"json",
        xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(data, text, request){
             var target = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
             alert('About to redirect to ' + target);
             document.location.href = target;
        },
        error: function(data){
            $("#std-login-error").html(data.fail);
        }
    });
```

**Edit** You are trying to do something very hard, involving a lot of moving parts: html, Javascript, php, ajax, sql, and redirection. It's admirable that you want to figure out how to do this; you'll learn a lot. If you need to just finish this task, forget about the ajax and just post the login form to php.

If you want to get this working, you should open up the **developer tools** on your browser ( on PCs, right-click/inspect on any platform).

The **Console tab** shows you diagnostic information about your pages. You can put `console.log(whatever);` lines in your Javascript and they'll show up on the console.

In the **Network tab** you can see the requests to and responses from your php AJAX endpoints including the Location header values and cookie values.

The **Source tab** is a debugger. You can set breakpoints on lines of Javascript so you can see what's happening. Suggestion: set breakpoints on the first lines of the `success:` and `error:` functions.

You can get yourself a **browser web extension** like [Edit This Cookie](http://www.editthiscookie.com/), to help you inspect the cookies fed to your browser by your ajax and GET/POST responses.

If you have a debugger server-side for your php, that will help too.  There's far more to learn about this than can appear in a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: It doesn't went well and nothing changed it's keeping me in the same index page with no errors and does not transfer me to home page